# How can i check update database in core data

Tags: iphone, core-data

Hi I am new in iphone app, i am just trying out some apps.
I am trying to add more data in my database, i just want to see where it is stored and my database updated or not.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know where the persistent store file is?

Answer (score 1):

The default for the template projects is that it will save a file named "NameOfProject.sqlite" into the apps document folder.

On the simulator, the app's directories will be in:

```
(user's home directory)/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/(build iOS version number)/(UUID string)/
```

The text in the "()" varies.

For example, one of my projects has a path:

```
(my home directory)/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/2E211069-AEF3-4F1F-9CA2-A18EF310F798
```

The name of the app's directory is a UUID and often changes so you have to constantly check.